# how to use slack web api users.profile.set to set an individual field of user's custom profile without purging other existing custom fields value?

Tags: slack, slack-api

how to use slack web api users.profile.set to set an individual field of user's custom profile without purging other existing custom fields value?

When I try users.profile.set to set an individual field, all other existing fields will be purged.
How can I aviod this?

[Before set profile, I have 2 fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idzIp.png)

[After set profile, other field will be empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9LLB.png)

Now I have to use users.profile.get to get all custom fields and replace JSON string of my targeting field value and send them all back to users.profile.set, which seems not convenient and safe.